# Зачем заниматься некропостингом?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

В данный момент пользователь [ksa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520359/ksa) занимается поднятием старых вопросов, на которые не были даны ответы. Я еще понимаю, когда этим Дух занимается, но здесь просто замусоривание главной страницы, как по мне. Такое ощущение, что поднимаются вообще все вопросы 2-3 летней давности без разбора.

Собственно вопроса 2:

- зачем <s>страдать херней</s> заниматься некропостингом так **массово**?
- и должно ли сообщество вообще реагировать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тоже хотел этот вопрос поднять... я так понимаю человек просто значок `Главред` очень хочет получить)

Comment: На значок и нацелился... Только не "Главред", он скоро у меня будет за другие правки... А за "Археолог". Там осталось вовсе немного и тут такой облом. :)

Comment: Может закрыть товарищу эту возможность? Ну невозможно же. Правит всякую ерунду, причем даже у закрытых вопросов.

Comment: @ksa Прекрати заниматься чепухой!

Comment: @Эникейщик, хорошо... :)

Comment: @Эникейщик он 500 правок уже набил, теперь перестанет)

Comment: @Павел, еще бы "Археолог" добить... :)

Comment: @ksa тогда лучше делать действительно значимые правки

Answer (score 16):

**Чем старше пост (вопрос или ответ), тем значимее должна быть правка**, и тем меньше таких правок подряд не будут вызывать раздражение. Это общее правило, которым руководствуюсь сам и рекомендую другим.

То чем занимается сейчас ksa, это не некропостинг (ksa не делает новых постов), а внесение косметических правок. Выглядит действительно раздражающе-бесполезным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Некропостинг же, как таковой (т.е. добавление ответов на старые вопросы), на SO очень даже приветствуется, т.к. это исполняет основную задачу платформы - пополнение Базы Знаний.

Comment: Стало интереснее... А что именно может улучшить старый вопрос?

Comment: @ksa например, проставление меток, уборка мусора, добавление конкретики и описания ситуации. Представьте себе, что старый вопрос это как статья на Википедии - что бы её могло улучшить?

Comment: Оно и просто текст "брикетом" не особо похож на статью. Так хоть текст будет читабельным и без ошибок...

Answer (score 12):

Участник заработал достаточно репутации, чтобы вносить какие угодно правки (без согласования с другими участниками) и он их вносит, пока не нарушает каких-либо правил сайта, например, пока явно не вандализирует содержимое. Более того, это явно стимулируется на сайте присутствием знака ["Археолог"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist).

Если кто-то считает эти правки назойливыми и мешающими просмотру нового контента, что ж, просто используйте не [главную страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), а [страницу вопросов с сортировкой по новизне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest). Всё. Проблема решена. Иначе получается так, что вы внушили себе ожидание видеть на главной только новые вопросы и недовольны тем, что это ожидание нарушается. Это ожидание ошибочно, главная так не работает. Не надо обвинять в этом участников, вносящих правки. Хотите изменить поведение главной страницы — опишите соответствующее [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), лучше сразу на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Запрещать кому-то делать правки, которые хотя бы даже на йоту делают сообщение лучше - не стоит. Новое это сообщение или старое, не важно.

Если исправили ваше личное сообщение и вам кажется, что оно стало хуже - всегда есть право откатить. Но не стоит забывать, что сообщение всё равно уже поднято и откатывать правку просто из-за вредности ("это моё сообщение, не надо его трогать") не рекомендуется.

Правило "Чем старше пост, тем значимее должна быть правка" я считаю ошибочным. Любая правка любого сообщения, делающая его лучше, имеет право быть и должна поощряться.

Comment: Я бы ве же внес какие-то ограничения. Скажем, не более 5 шт. в день (понимаю, что движок никто править не будет, остается уповать на моральные качества "Археолога" (если донести до него такое правило))

Comment: @avp какая цель такого ограничения?

Comment: Ограничить "загрязнение" главной страницы

Comment: @avp что такое "загрязнение главной страницы"?

Comment: Когда на нее попаадает много незначимых изменений

Comment: @avp "незначимых" для кого и по какому критерию? Почему наполнение главной без правок будет считаться "значимым"?

Comment: Я имел в виду старые темы, в которые вносятся правки. Их процент на главной странице не должен  быть большим. Отвлекают от новых

Comment: @avp главная и не должна показывать исключительно новые, новые надо смотреть в соответствующим разделе (на этом как раз сделан акцент в моем ответе).

Comment: Значит после выходных "Археолога" пройду! :-)

Comment: То есть, следуя подобной логике, я могу в один присест сделать ачиву ради ачивы? Загадив главную на пару часов минимум. Сколько там вопросов нужно поднять, 100? Ну что ж...

Comment: @DaemonHK да, конечно. Если каждая правка будет полезной, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: @DaemonHK просто откати всё, что ksa сделал, вот тебе и полезные правки. Судя по одному из скриншотов в ответе Кромстера, он текст сделал хуже.