# Как бороться с низкокачественными проверками в очередях первых сообщений?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, нытьё

На мете уже было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11514/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%85)
, которое затрагивало тему моего вопроса. Но я подниму хоть и связанную, но немного другую. Дело в том, что я только что увидел следующее:

[image: [Проверка низкого качества]]

Честно говоря, я уже давно хотел создать этот вопрос на мете, и я часто встречаю проверки не очень высокого качества в очередях первых сообщений. **Проверка со скриншота просто подтолкнула меня сделать это прямо сейчас**.

Проблема-то собственно в том, что очередь `первые вопросы` теряет смысл. Проверки перестают быть проверками. Я очень часто вижу, что при проверке вопроса можно было сделать что-то большее. Например, участник выбирает "выглядит нормально", хотя сообщение можно улучшить. Я предлагаю правку, и её принимают (то есть она приносит пользу).

Другой пример. Вот временная шкала одного вопроса:

[image: история]

Я тем не менее позже правил это сообщение:

[image: моя правка]

Мало того, что его можно было править, можно было хотя бы оставить отзыв с просьбой не добавлять код/ошибки картинками или хотя бы попросить сделать скрин поменьше (там половина скрина даже не нужна). Если вы не хотите править или оставлять отзыв, то хотя бы пропустите этот вопрос. Но нет, "выглядит нормально".

В первом случае может быть проверяющий и мискликнул. Но случаев по типу второго я видел много.

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то повысить качество проверок в очереди первых сообщений? Как бороться с проверками-пустышками?

**P.S**: я не пытаюсь обидеть или оскорбить какого-то конкретного участника. Я просто хочу обратить внимание на ситуацию.

И я не считаю мой вопрос дубликатом обсуждения про золотую лихорадку, так как там вопрос звучал по-другому:

> Как сообщество относится к практике получения золотых знаков за счёт набивания счётчика проверок спровоцированными аудитами? И почему модераторы, обладая инструментом лишения участников привилегии доступа к очередям проверок, не применяют его?

**И ещё:** простите за [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91) =).

Comment: Автор, ничего не имею против вас, но по-моему мнению вы очень часто делаете минималистичные правки (SO их особо не одобряет), которые эти же люди аппрувят (хотя по идее не должны), поэтому для меня было очень странным увидеть этот пост от вашего имени))

Comment: @Павел возможно. Если моя правка кажется вам бесполезной - отклоняйте. Но как на счёт первого сообщения?

Comment: Тут в целом ничего не сделать. Человек не нарушает никаких правил сообщества, сообщество модерируется людьми и раз он набрал такую репутацию, значит имеет право голосовать по своему желанию. Вообще, если бы он голосовал всегда "все ок", то не проходил бы специальные проверки, которые как раз для этого и придуманы (но не уверен, что они работают и выдают наказание).

Comment: [По теме о блокировке доступа к очередям проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11760/337980) — без ответа

Comment: Может промахнулся? Я так иногда промахиваюсь, когда много проверок. Посмотрел, почитал, думаешь, надо коммент оставить, тык галку, заносишь мышку над кнопкой, глаз поднимаешь, а тыкнул "Выглядит нормально" и палец жмет кнопку выбора... блииин... ну ладно, кому то "Прокатило". Я не знаю, можно ли передумать в очереди проверок, специально не искал, но сходу не нашел

Comment: @SwaD я уже года два наблюдаю как он постоянно «промахивается»

Comment: @Павел "SO их [незначительные правки] особо не одобряет" - посмотрите [этот пост на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12391/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc) Лично я стараюсь совсем бесполезные правки не предлагать. Но если вы про оформление `понятий_вот_так`, то это улучшает читаемость вопроса. Правки орфографии и пунктуации, а так же переписывание заголовков - я считаю всё это важным.

Comment: @Зонтик это лишь подтверждение моим словам, SO - это сами участники, недовольны были очень многие подобным, плюс ещё видел руководство на сайте про то "как делать правки", и там тоже написано, что незначительные правки лучше не делать (пока не удалось ссылку найти, если найду - отправлю)

Comment: @Зонтик это важно и действительно улучшает вопрос, но не настолько, как вы думаете, в приоритете всегда правки, которые очень важны: вставка кода в блоки, удаление излишних частей, все моменты, без исправления которых понять вопрос очень тяжело, а все остальное как по мне допустимо и в исходном виде, тем более на вопросах 5-летней давности

Comment: @Павел посмотрите ответ `@αλεχολυτ`. Цитата из него: "Запрещать кому-то делать правки, которые хотя бы даже на йоту делают сообщение лучше - не стоит." Ещё цитата из того же ответа: "Любая правка любого сообщения, делающая его лучше, имеет право быть и должна поощряться."

Comment: @Зонтик я не модератор и тем более не руководство, и запрещать вам ничего не могу, всего лишь высказал своё мнение по поводу того, почему считаю подобные правки очень мало помогающими сообществу, есть много вопросов, которые нуждаются в серьёзных доработках, я бы на вашем месте сфокусировался на них

Comment: Опять кто-то [жмет не думая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/899679)(

Comment: @Глеб товарищ Ник жмёт на всё принять и всё выглядит нормально... я конечно не самый лучший проверяющий, но даже меня он напрягает, такое ощущение что он бот ХДД

Comment: @Amgarak, [видели](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13179/Невнимательная-работа-в-очередях-проверок) же, да?

Comment: @Глеб видел, да и периодически в очереди проверок тоже вижу, но как я понял из разных обсуждений - уже как несколько лет товарищ Ник фармит очивки принимая и одобряя все что только можно по кд.

Comment: @Amgarak, а я даже не периодически — я каждый день вижу штук по пять его некачественных проверок... И никто с этим ничего сделать не может — 70k ж, не кто-нибудь там.

Comment: @Глеб так то ответы он хорошие даёт, свою репу оправдывает, тут без претензий. Но то что кликер закрывает за него тикеты проверок это к гадалке не ходи. Можно конечно ещё раз тему на мете поднять, но кажется это ничего не изменит.